# Avoiding duplicates during insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-insert

I am working on a stored procedure that currently builds our fact table every hour. Currently, during hourly refresh it truncates the table and Inserts new data every time. I am trying to change that to only delete rows that are not needed and append new rows. I have gotten the delete part, but currently, as the ID column (Primary Key) is created upon Insertion, I am not sure how to avoid the insertion of duplicate records, which is what I am currently seeing.

Currently, the stored procedure inserts the primary key (ID) upon insert. I've taken out the truncate table query and replaced that with a delete query. Now I need to work on avoiding duplicates during the insert.

```
   --INSERT DATA FROM TEMP TABLE TO FACTBP
   INSERT INTO dbo.FactBP
   SELECT 
   [SOURCE]
  ,[DC_ORDER_NUMBER]
  ,[CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID]
  ,[BILL_TO]
  ,[CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE]
  ,[SHIP_TO]
  ,[CUSTOMER_NAME]
  ,[SALES_ORDER]
  ,[ORDER_CARRIER]
  ,[CARRIER_SERVICE_ID]
  ,[CREATE_DATE]
  ,[CREATE_TIME]
  ,[ALLOCATION_DATE]
  ,[REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE]
  ,[ADJ_REQ_SHIP]
  ,[CANCEL_DATE]
  ,[DISPATCH_DATE]
  ,[RELEASED_DATE]
  ,[RELEASED_TIME]
  ,[PRIORITY_ORDER]
  ,[SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER]
  ,[ORDER_HDR_STATUS]
  ,[ORDER_STATUS]
  ,[DELIVERY_NUMBER]
  ,[DCMS_ORDER_TYPE]
  ,[ORDER_TYPE]
  ,[MATERIAL]
  ,[QUALITY]
  ,[MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1]
  ,[SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1]
  ,[SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2]
  ,[SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3]
  ,[DIVISION]
  ,[DIVISION_DESC]
  ,[ORDER_QTY]
  ,[ORDER_SELECTED_QTY]
  ,[CARTON_PARCEL_ID]
  ,[CARTON_ID]
  ,[SHIP_DATE]
  ,[SHIP_TIME]
  ,[PACKED_DATE]
  ,[PACKED_TIME]
  ,[ADJ_PACKED_DATE]
  ,[FULL_CASE_PULL_STATUS]
  ,[CARRIER_ID]
  ,[TRAILER_ID]
  ,[WAVE_NUMBER]
  ,[DISPATCH_RELEASE_PRIORITY]
  ,[CARTON_TOTE_COUNT]
  ,[PICK_PACK_METHOD]
  ,[RELEASED_QTY]
  ,[SHIP_QTY]
  ,[MERCHANDISE_STYLE]
  ,[PICK_WAREHOUSE]
  ,[PICK_AREA]
  ,[PICK_ZONE]
  ,[PICK_AISLE]
  ,EST_DEL_DATE
  ,null
  --,[ID]
  FROM #TEMP_FACT
  --code for avoiding duplicates

   --CLEAR ALL DATA FROM FACTBP
   DELETE FROM dbo.FactBP
   WHERE SHIP_DATE < DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, 
   DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-2,0)) and SHIP_DATE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Is there any candidate key that does not include the `ID` column?  If so, you can use that to find duplicates.

Comment: Define what a duplicate is? Also you really don't need the IS NOT NULL in your delete. It is completely redundant as NULL will not evaluate to less than any calculation.

Comment: I would left join the table #TEMP_FACT to dbo.FactBP on whatever criteria you would use to define a duplicate.  Then the where clause `where dbo.FactBP.somecolumnusedinjoin is null`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check against the [natural key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key).  Since you're talking about a fact table, the natural key is probably the combination of a lot of fields.  If we assume SOURCE and DC_ORDER_NUMBER make up the natural key, this should work:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.FactBP

SELECT 
  t.[SOURCE]
, t.[DC_ORDER_NUMBER]
, t.[CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID]
, t.[BILL_TO]
, t.[CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE]
, t.[SHIP_TO]
, t.[CUSTOMER_NAME]
, t.[SALES_ORDER]
, t.[ORDER_CARRIER]
, t.[CARRIER_SERVICE_ID]
, t.[CREATE_DATE]
, t.[CREATE_TIME]
, t.[ALLOCATION_DATE]
, t.[REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE]
, t.[ADJ_REQ_SHIP]
, t.[CANCEL_DATE]
, t.[DISPATCH_DATE]
, t.[RELEASED_DATE]
, t.[RELEASED_TIME]
, t.[PRIORITY_ORDER]
, t.[SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER]
, t.[ORDER_HDR_STATUS]
, t.[ORDER_STATUS]
, t.[DELIVERY_NUMBER]
, t.[DCMS_ORDER_TYPE]
, t.[ORDER_TYPE]
, t.[MATERIAL]
, t.[QUALITY]
, t.[MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1]
, t.[SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1]
, t.[SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2]
, t.[SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3]
, t.[DIVISION]
, t.[DIVISION_DESC]
, t.[ORDER_QTY]
, t.[ORDER_SELECTED_QTY]
, t.[CARTON_PARCEL_ID]
, t.[CARTON_ID]
, t.[SHIP_DATE]
, t.[SHIP_TIME]
, t.[PACKED_DATE]
, t.[PACKED_TIME]
, t.[ADJ_PACKED_DATE]
, t.[FULL_CASE_PULL_STATUS]
, t.[CARRIER_ID]
, t.[TRAILER_ID]
, t.[WAVE_NUMBER]
, t.[DISPATCH_RELEASE_PRIORITY]
, t.[CARTON_TOTE_COUNT]
, t.[PICK_PACK_METHOD]
, t.[RELEASED_QTY]
, t.[SHIP_QTY]
, t.[MERCHANDISE_STYLE]
, t.[PICK_WAREHOUSE]
, t.[PICK_AREA]
, t.[PICK_ZONE]
, t.[PICK_AISLE]
, t.EST_DEL_DATE
, null
--,[ID]

FROM #TEMP_FACT t
  left outer join dbo.FactBP f on f.[SOURCE] = t.[SOURCE]
                              and f.[DC_ORDER_NUMBER] = t.[DC_ORDER_NUMBER]

where f.[SOURCE] is null
```

Adjust the join and the `WHERE` clause to match the natural key of the table.

You should also take another look at your `DELETE` script.  Do you really want to delete all records with a `SHIP_DATE < 2019-07-31 23:59:59.000`?  Or should that be `<=`?  Maybe this will work better (and simpler):

```sql
DELETE FROM dbo.FactBP
WHERE SHIP_DATE < cast(dateadd(day, 1, EOMONTH(getdate(), -3)) as datetime2)
  and SHIP_DATE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Using a where not exists clause is usually preferred for this kind of thing, isn't it? Same idea, but instead of a join you would simply say ```from #TEMP_FACT t where not exists (select 1 from dbo.FactBP f on t.[SOURCE] = f.[SOURCE] and t.[DC_ORDER_NUMBER] = f.[DC_ORDER_NUMBER])``` since you don't need any of the actual results from factbp

Comment: Ah ok I got it. I'll try that. THanks!

Comment: @dougp that delete statement you provided continues to throw a 'System.OutOfMemoryException' and I don't really understand why that is the case.

Comment: Hi @UmairAhmed, the reason for that is because your server was pulling all of the information into memory twice over, whereas a not exists query is more efficient and doesn't do that.

Comment: @SeanBrookins that makes sense. Thanks for that!